# scheme iteration of summing in lists

Tags: list, sum, scheme

i want to ask if someone wants to help me with a iterative scheme code that gives the sum of two lists. I already have the recursive version of the code.

```
(define (sum-lists l1 l2)(cond ((and (null? l1) (null? l2)) '())
    ((null? l1) l2)
    ((null? l2) l1)
    (else (cons (+ (car l1) (car l2)) (sum-lists (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The general "iterative procedure" recipe:

1. Write a helper function that takes an accumulator parameter.
   Create each intermediate result in the accumulator.
2. When you terminate the recursion, return the accumulator.
3. Pass it a suitable initial accumulator.

It's common when transforming lists to accumulate the result in reverse and then reverse the result when you're done.

A trivial example, incrementing each list element by one:

```
(define (add-1 ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (cons (+ 1 (car ls)) (add-1 (cdr ls)))))
```

To make it iterative, create a helper function where you `cons` to the accumulator instead of the recursive result:

```
(define (add-one ls acc)
  (if (null? ls)
      (reverse acc)
      (add-one (cdr ls) (cons (+ 1 (car ls)) acc))))
```

(Note that, except for the introduction of `acc`, the recursion contains the same parts as before but in a different order.)

Then you start it off with an empty accumulator:

```
(define (add-1 ls)
  (add-one ls '()))
```

Your case has slightly more involved base cases since you need to accomodate inputs of different lengths.
Finishing it left as an exercise.

(Another exercise: figure out why your first condition, `(and (null? l1) (null? l2))`, is unnecessary.)